# sed , awk : find pattern and 20 char before

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I have any too long file with this pattern :

```
"196","02041873983107165016.jpg","0","0","0","0009.jpg","1"
"197","22326275984445946358.jpg","0","0","0","0011.jpg","1"
"198","94656137600921259484.jpg","0","0","0","0012.jpg","1"
"199","14489943688842089858.jpg","0","0","0","0013.jpg","1"
"200","04120962316412927503.jpg","0","0","0","0008.jpg","1"
"201","24360101806918799057.jpg","0","0","0","0009.jpg","1"
"202","48341366030411757581.jpg","0","0","0","0012.jpg","1"
"203","55697947255646026367.jpg","0","0","0","0013.jpg","1"
"204","73425273021963647924.jpg","0","0","0","2s0l92c.jpg","
.................
```

I want get file name here : .jpg and 20 char before :

```
73425273021963647924.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
............
```

How can do it with grep , sed or awk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk -F\" '{ print $4 }' file
```

Output:

```
02041873983107165016.jpg
22326275984445946358.jpg
94656137600921259484.jpg
14489943688842089858.jpg
04120962316412927503.jpg
24360101806918799057.jpg
48341366030411757581.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
73425273021963647924.jpg
```

Comment: Imagine you had OPs question but not the sample input, this only works for this specific example and does not take into account the number of char before.

Comment: @Jidder There's a chance that the OP just didn't see an easier way to do it. And I also imagined your solution (using `substr`) but I chose to not make it complicated.

Comment: @Jidder I'm with konsolebox on this one, I think this is a classic case of an OP telling us what solution they want because that's all they know instead of telling us what their requirements are. Most or all solutions here rely on the input being exactly as shown (e.g. consider what yours would do with a line that doesn't contain `.jpg`) just like this answer does.

Comment: @EdMorton I understand that OP probably didn't know this was an option but the title of the question is finding 20 chars before a pattern. this answer does not include a pattern nor a way to find previous chars. If i had searched for this question and this was the only answer i would be quite disappointed and it would be of little help. I suppose the question could be changed though.Also .jpg is just an example of a pattern to search for.

Answer (score 2):

try this grep line:

```
grep -Eo '[^",]{20}[.]jpg' file
```

with your example, it outputs:

```
kent$  grep -Eo '[^",]{20}[.]jpg' f  
02041873983107165016.jpg
22326275984445946358.jpg
94656137600921259484.jpg
14489943688842089858.jpg
04120962316412927503.jpg
24360101806918799057.jpg
48341366030411757581.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
73425273021963647924.jpg
```

Comment: I second on Jidder's comment to the answer given by konsolebox: the answer you suggest is not strictly compliant with the OP's request "the (first) occurrence of ".jpg" on the line and the previous 20 characters (or up to the beginning of the line), whatever these characters are. I am sure you noticed the strange behaviour of the simpler and more straight-to-the-point `grep -Eo '.{20}\.jpg' essai` which goes wrong on the last line of the input, but we have to face that rather than to provide the `[^",]` workaround, hehe... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To extract 20 characters before `.jpg` and include `.jpg` using awk.

```
awk '$0=substr($0,index($0,".jpg")-20,24)' file

02041873983107165016.jpg
22326275984445946358.jpg
94656137600921259484.jpg
14489943688842089858.jpg
04120962316412927503.jpg
24360101806918799057.jpg
48341366030411757581.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
73425273021963647924.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

To be really generic and extract the first occurrence of ".jpg" on every line as well as the (up to) 20 characters before that, I suggest the following two-step **sed** solution:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.{,20}\.jpg).*/\1/;s/.*(.{24})/\1/' file
02041873983107165016.jpg
22326275984445946358.jpg
94656137600921259484.jpg
14489943688842089858.jpg
04120962316412927503.jpg
24360101806918799057.jpg
48341366030411757581.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
73425273021963647924.jpg
25273021963647924.jpg
```

This is for an answer to the edited OP question, with a last line containing only 17 characters before the first occurrence of ".jpg". We have to do it in two steps with sed because, as with **grep**, we cannot include `.*` *before* the pattern save within the parenthesis, otherwise it will match the *second* occurrence of ".jpg" on the line.

Otherwise, if the input is really as simple as given by the OP and with no bad surprise, we could go as far as using a fixed-width string extraction with **cut**:

```
$ cut -c 8-31 file
```

gives the same desired output:

```
02041873983107165016.jpg
22326275984445946358.jpg
94656137600921259484.jpg
14489943688842089858.jpg
04120962316412927503.jpg
24360101806918799057.jpg
48341366030411757581.jpg
55697947255646026367.jpg
73425273021963647924.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that input, all you need is:

```
cut -d\" -f4
```